# laravel 5.8 how to use if and else if functions in laravel controller

Tags: laravel

> in laravel 5.8 i am trying to pass updated value in users table status
>   columns by default value is 'PENDING', if i pass value 'APPROVED' in
>   'status' columns using update.blade.php form,

```
 DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->increment('wallet', '1000' );
```

> this code no needed to work.
>
> else i pass value 'REJECTED' in 'status' columns using
>   update.blade.php form, in this time this code

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->increment('wallete', '1000' );
```

> should  work to store value '1000' in users table 'wallet' column
>
> how to create this logic Query using if, if else ,else if in laravel
>   5.8 controller

```
public function pan_status_update(Request $request, $id)
  {

      $pan_status_update = Pan::where('status','=','PENDING')->find($id);
      $pan_status_update['status'] = $request->status;
      $pan_status_update['manager_id'] = Auth::user()->id; 


      DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->increment('wallete', '1000' );
      $pan_status_update->save();
  return redirect('Pan_request')->with('success','UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY .',);
  }
```

Comment: have you tried `if($request->status == 'Approved'){ //update }elseif($request->status == 'Rejected'){ //dont update }else{ //do something }`

Comment: no i am new in laravel

Comment: give it a try to see if it works for you

Comment: its not working

Comment: can you add the updated code?

Comment: yes i added code

Comment: can you write full code i will check that put your modified code in answer section

Comment: if($request->status == 'Approved')
{ DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->increment('wallete', '1000' ); }
elseif($request->status == 'Rejected')
{ DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->increment('wallete', '1000' ); }
else{ DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->increment('wallete', '1000' ); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, try this, it will only update if the status is set to rejected,

```
public function pan_status_update(Request $request, $id)
  {

    $pan_status_update = Pan::where('id', $id)
                                ->where('status', 'pending')
                                ->first();
    if(!$pan_status_update){
     return redirect()->back()->withStatus('Not Found');
    }

    if($request->status == 'Approved'){ 
      //shouldn't work
    }elseif($request->status == 'Rejected'){
      DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->increment('wallet', '1000' );
    }else{
     return redirect()->back();
    }
    return redirect('Pan_request')->with('success','UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY .',);
```

Comment: i have another question already i posted , no one can  answered perfectly if you can ,  solve  that (in laravel how to display image in home.blade.php or any page, from out side of laravel project (out side of root folder)